# Syncing google calendar with custom calendar

Tags: oauth, google-calendar-api, authsub

I am using google calendar API to sync google calendar with our custom calendar. Right now I am trying it with a crude way by asking user if he/she wants to sync their calendar with google or not. If they say "yes" , I show them login screen where they have to enter their google user id and password and the calendar will be synced. But now when I change the month , the screen gets refreshed and all login information is lost and that changed month doesn't show up the events from google calendar.

What is a best way for authentication AuthSub, OAuth or the crude way I mentioned for testing locally? I really don't know if I can use OAuth locally.

Answer (score 1):

**Never, ever** require your user to enter credentials from other site into yours.

That's why protocols like [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) were created, and they are meant to be used.

Comment: well, before making my application live, I want to test it locally. OAuth needs to register the domain. How do I handle that?

Comment: You actually want a local OAuth server just for testing?